# Special properties of $32$

Tags: number-theory

Is $32$ the only positive integer with the following properties?

- It is a Leyland Number, i.e., it is a number expressible in the form $a^b+b^a$ where $a,b>1$ are positive integers.
- It is of the form $x^x+y^y+z^z$ for positive integers $x,y,z$.

A quick search using the first few Leyland numbers indicates the same. However, this is pretty small evidence considering the quick growth of $x^x$ over positive integers. How can one attempt to prove a result of this sort?

Comment: How far have you checked the positive integers whether they have both the properties ? Additionally, are $a,b$ allowed to be equal ?

Comment: No duplicates apart from $32$ for $a,b\le 500$ and $x,y,z\le 100$, so a second number of this kind must exceed $3\cdot 10^{150}$

Comment: @Peter Yes, $a=b$ is allowed (like in the case of $32$ itself).